# How to set unique id on html form in while loop

Tags: php, loops, post, while-loop

How I can set unique id for html form which is in while loop, and get this id when check is the form is submit? You can check out my code:

```
while($row_lessons = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryLessons)) {
    echo 'someinfohere';                
    if(isset($_POST['buy'])) { 
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET credits = credits - ".$row_lessons['price']." WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ");
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `lessonpurchases` (lesson_id, user_id, date) VALUES ('".$row_lessons['id']."', '".$_SESSION['userid']."', '".time()."')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
    echo '
        Цена: '.levche($row_lessons['price']).'лв. <br />
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="buy" value="Купи" />
        </form>';
}
```

The unique id is needed, because when submit the form the mysql queries are being executed for all results in loop.

Comment: @Rakesh Jakhar, okay, but how to check in the php which form id is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple:

```
$i = 1;
while($row_lessons = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryLessons)) {
    echo 'someinfohere';                
    if(isset($_POST['buy'.$i])) { 
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET credits = credits - ".$row_lessons['price']." WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ");
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `lessonpurchases` (lesson_id, user_id, date) VALUES ('".$row_lessons['id']."', '".$_SESSION['userid']."', '".time()."')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
    echo '
        Цена: '.levche($row_lessons['price']).'лв. <br />
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="buy'.$i.'" value="Купи" />
        </form>';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**uniqid()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) as follow

```
$formId = uniqid();
```

In your form you can use it like

```
<form action="" method="post" id="<?php echo $formId;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="formId" value="<?php echo $formId;?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="buy" value="Купи" />
</form>
```

On form submission you will get the `formId` by using `$_REQUEST['formId']`